# Is $A ⅋ (B \otimes C) \vdash (A⅋B) \otimes C$ provable in MLL?

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus, linear-logic

Consider the multiplicative fragment of linear logic (MLL) which only consists of the multiplicative connectives *tensor* and *par* together with the inference rules *axiom*, *cut*, *$\otimes$* and ⅋. I was able to show that $(A⅋B) \otimes C \vdash A ⅋ (B \otimes C) $ holds. Is the other entailment $A ⅋ (B \otimes C) \vdash (A⅋B) \otimes C$ also provable in MLL? I could not come up with a proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axioms and rules of MLLL are valid in classical logic if we read tensor as $\land$ and par as $\lor$. Since $A\lor(B\land C)$ doesn't classically imply $(A\lor B)\land C$, MLL doesn't prove your sequent.

Comment: So MLL is a fragment of classical logic?

Comment: Yes; by inspection of the rules of MLL.